# Using "Subdivide Polygon" in ModelBuilder with an iteration via the split angle (value from input feature class) to split polygons in their centres

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, splitting, iteration

I have a lot of polygons that I would like to split automatically in the centre/into two equal parts in ModelBuilder. My idea was to first determine the orientation of the polygons using the Minimum Bounding Geometry tool (option: Rectangle by width). And then to split the polygons using Subdivide Polygon tool and the information about the split angle. In the ModelBuilder, iteration should be carried out for each polygon using the Split Angle parameter.
I have tried various iterators (e.g. Iterate Field Values & Iterate Feature Selection), but cannot get the corresponding split angle to be used for each polygon.
Here is an attempt (unfortunately the split angle from either the first or last row of the attribute table is always used):
[image]

Are there any ideas on how I can solve the iteration using the split angle of each polygon?

I have worked with the ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro, but I am open to suggestions.

After trying to implement @Hornbydd's suggestions, my model looks like this:
[image]

Unfortunately, it still doesn't work properly. I think the model iterates through all rows of the attribute table, but I only get the result of the last row as output.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the help file for the subdivide tool it appears the split angle is applied to all features in the input layer. You need to apply the orientation value created by minimum bounding tool to each INDIVIDUAL polygon. So you need a feature selection iterator. I think you need to step over each bounding geometry get the polygon id and split angle. Use id to select the polygon itself and feed the angle into the subdivide tool along with a layer of one selection. So the model logic is nothing like your first attempt.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that helps me a lot. However, I have no experience with iterators, so I have a query. 
So you mean I have to put the iterator in front of the Minimum Bounding Geometry tool? 
But then I have to add something that outputs the split angle of each polygon as a model variable, right? Because I need this variable for the Subdivide Polygon tool. 
I have not yet understood how to select each individual polygon and feed its split angle into the subdivide polygon tool?

Comment: You have your bounding geometry output feeding into a feature selection iterator, then use the model only tools get Field Value to get your angle value, Use ID (the value you are stepping over in the iterator) to select the polygon and feed angle and selection into subdivide tool.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I have understood how you would connect the individual elements. 
Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I think the model iterates through all rows of the attribute table, but I only get the result of the last row as output. 
Then something is probably not working with the selection of all individual polygons via the ID? Or do I need an extra tool/element in my model to save the output of each polygon?

Comment: Can't answer your question without seeing your model, edit your question and insert an update section showing the latest.